# Find an energy functional for the nonlinear viscous oscillator $x' = v$, $v' =-b(v)v-k(x)x$, $t>0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations

Consider the nonlinear viscous oscillator
$$\begin{cases} 
x' = v\\
v' =-b(v)v-k(x)x,\quad t>0,   \\
\end{cases}$$

where $(x,v)$ is the position and velocity of the oscillator. Here $b : \mathbb R\to[0,\infty)$ is a
continuous nonlinear friction, and $k : \mathbb R\to(0,\infty)$ is a continuous nonlinear spring
restitution. Find an energy functional for the oscillator and use it to show that
$$sup(\vert x(t)\vert+\vert v(t)+\vert v'(t)\vert)\le C\lt \infty ,$$
where $C$ is a constant depending on the initial energy of the oscillator, $b$ and $k$.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. What have you tried? Can you do this for a simpler problem? Have you seen a similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply the first equation by $x \cdot k(x)$ and the second by $v$, then sum both of them. You obtain
$$
x k(x) x'+vv'=-b(v)v^2.
$$
Let $V(x)$ such that $V'(x)=x k(x)$, then
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{v^2}{2}+V(x)\right)=-b(v)2^2\leq 0
$$
Consider the energy function $E(x,v)=\frac{v^2}{2}+V(x)$. Since it is not increasing in time,
$$
\frac{v^2}{2}+V(x)\leq E(0).
$$
Now, by physical grounds, $k(x)\geq 0$, then $V(x)$ is bounded from below; we can assume  $V(x)\geq 0$ without loss of generality. Therefore
$$
|v(t)|\leq \sqrt{2E(0)}.
$$
If $k(x)\geq c>0$ (the spring does not become soft for $x\to\infty$), from $V(x)\leq E(0)$ you can also deduce $|x|\leq c_1$. Then the bound $|v'(t)|\leq c_2$ follows from the second differential equation.

Comment: why $$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{v^2}{2}+V(x)\right)=-b(v)2^2\leq 0
$$

Comment: I'm sorry. There was a typo in the answer: I have corrected it. Now, work out the derivative: $\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{v^2}{2}+V(x)\right)=vv'+V'(x) x'$ and $V'(x)=x k(x)$

Comment: Thast was good, thank u so much @guestDiego